# Function was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Quick.gallery (http://quick.gallery) script on my website but I'm getting some erros with Firebug:

When I try to access http://www.portaloficial.com.br/fotos.php, Firebug show me some erros like "js=js_viewer was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: the server for some of the scripts (e,g src="fotos/?js=linkify") is sending `Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8` - scripts aren't `text/html` - they should be `text/javascript; charset=UTF-8` - not sure why your server is doing that

Comment: Read the article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had this issue before, when I was referencing a mistyped URL, so the reason for content-type html was, that I actually got a HTTP 404 error page.

Comment: Didn't believe this initially, more digging uncovered that my static files weren't being served correctly and thus the error represented a 404

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. In my case, the debian package installation of my software failed without me noticing. No symlinks were created and thus, the files could not be served.