# how to fix countdown clock JS HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My JS is not working on my website.
Im quite new to this and im setting up a website but I want a timer to show when the site will be active.

I must be missing something - I believe the error lies withing the JS as i know little about this.

For now I just want to know why the script is not working. Once I have a better understanding of how the code is linked to html I shall start trying to understand what its doing.

Any help is really appreciated.

```js
  
        var target_date = new Date().getTime() + (1000*3600*48); // set the countdown date
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units
        
        var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element
        
        getCountdown();
        
        setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);
        
        function getCountdown(){
        
         // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
         var current_date = new Date().getTime();
         var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
        
         days = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) );
         seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
           
         hours = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 3600) );
         seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
            
         minutes = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 60) );
         seconds = pad( parseInt( seconds_left % 60 ) );
        
         // format countdown string + set tag value
         countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
        }
        
        function pad(n) {
         return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
        }
```

```css
                body
                {
                 width:1000px;
                 height:1000px;
                 position:relative;
                 top:10px;
                 margin:auto;
                 background-image:url('bg copy.png');
                }
                
                #Header
                {
                 width:1000px;
                 background-image:url('Logo 3 small.png');
                 background-repeat:no-repeat;
                 background-position:center;
                }
                
                #Middle
                {
                 width:1000px;
                }
                
                #Soon
                {
                 height:100px;
                 width:1000px;
                 font-family:"Malgun Gothic Semilight";
                 font-size:20px;
                 color:Black;
                 
                }
                
                #Timer
                {
                 height:200px;
                 width:1000px;
                }
                
                #Bottom
                {
                 font-size:80px;
                }
                

                #countdown{
                 width: 465px;
                 height: 112px;
                 text-align: center;
                 background: #222;
                 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222); 
                 background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
                 background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
                 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #222, #333, #333, #222);
                 border: 1px solid #111;
                 border-radius: 5px;
                 box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                 margin: auto;
                 padding: 24px 0;
                 position: absolute;
                  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
                }
                
                #countdown:before{
                 content:"";
                 width: 8px;
                 height: 65px;
                 background: #444;
                 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555); 
                 background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
                 background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
                 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
                 border: 1px solid #111;
                 border-top-left-radius: 6px;
                 border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
                 display: block;
                 position: absolute;
                 top: 48px; left: -10px;
                }
                
                #countdown:after{
                 content:"";
                 width: 8px;
                 height: 65px;
                 background: #444;
                 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555); 
                 background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
                 background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
                 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #555, #444, #444, #555);
                 border: 1px solid #111;
                 border-top-right-radius: 6px;
                 border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
                 display: block;
                 position: absolute;
                 top: 48px; right: -10px;
                }
                
                #countdown #tiles{
                 position: relative;
                 z-index: 1;
                }
                
                #countdown #tiles > span{
                 width: 92px;
                 max-width: 92px;
                 font: bold 48px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
                 text-align: center;
                 color: #111;
                 background-color: #ddd;
                 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee); 
                 background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
                 background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
                 background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbb, #eee);
                 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
                 border-radius: 3px;
                 box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                 margin: 0 7px;
                 padding: 18px 0;
                 display: inline-block;
                 position: relative;
                }
                
                #countdown #tiles > span:before{
                 content:"";
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 13px;
                 background: #111;
                 display: block;
                 padding: 0 3px;
                 position: absolute;
                 top: 41%; left: -3px;
                 z-index: -1;
                }
                
                #countdown #tiles > span:after{
                 content:"";
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 1px;
                 background: #eee;
                 border-top: 1px solid #333;
                 display: block;
                 position: absolute;
                 top: 48%; left: 0;
                }
                
                #countdown .labels{
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 25px;
                 text-align: center;
                 position: absolute;
                 bottom: 8px;
                }
                
                #countdown .labels li{
                 width: 102px;
                 font: bold 15px 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
                 color: #f47321;
                 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
                 text-align: center;
                 text-transform: uppercase;
                 display: inline-block;
```

```html
            <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <title>SPAutoTech Home</title>
            <link href="localcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="java.js"></script>
            </head>
            
              <body>
              
                <div id="Header" style="height:400px">
                </div>
                
                <div id="Middle" style="height:300px">
                
                  <div id="Soon">
                  </div>
                   
                  <div id="counter"> 
                   <div id="countdown">
                     <div id='tiles'></div>
                     <div class="labels">
                       <li>Days</li>
                       <li>Hours</li>
                       <li>Mins</li>
                       <li>Secs</li>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                  <script src="java.js"></script>
                  
                  <div id="Bottom" style="height:300px">
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                  
                <div id="Bottom1" style="height:300px">
                 <center><b>COMING SOON</b></center>
                </div>
            
              </body>
              
            </html>
```

Comment: Have you opened your browser's developer tools (F12) and looked at the Console tab for any errors? What is it that's "not working"? It seems to be counting down to me.

Comment: You do know that you've got 2 external script references to `java.js`, and two different reference for JQuery, right?

Comment: no - thats new to me

Comment: The resource from “https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).[Learn More]

Comment: would x2 java references matter ? i put another incase I had done one incorrect

Comment: It seems to be running fine, you just have to scroll down to where the counter is positioned to see it.  (You're not using jQuery in this code, so the link to jQuery isn't needed.  But if you're using jQuery elsewhere, the google CDN only has v3.3.1; if you want the 3.4 version use https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js.)

Comment: It just doesn't make any sense to have redundant code. And, the code you've shown doesn't even use JQuery.

Comment: I was playing around with some J Query earlier, this is when the confusion kicked.

Comment: Have you looked at your developer's tools Network tab? Have you tried actually browsing to: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528748/function-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff

Comment: It does not work though, Its not showing an actualy count down just all the background graphics. www.SPautotech.co.uk/index,html is the page im trying to get it working on

Comment: We can't/won't diagnose external code. The code you've provided here (although it does have some problems) does work as you can see by pressing the Run code snippet button. If it's not working on your actual page, then you've got a different problem.

Comment: Breaking protocol a bit and looking at your site: that page doesn't contain any javascript, you must have forgotten to include it.  (You've also got some case-sensitivity problems; Index.html is not the same as index.html)

Comment: Thanks Daniel - that would explain why my index page wasnt loading as default. Ok i must be missing something here. When you say theres no javascript. I have a .JS file with the script in ir linked to my HTML - hence the  <script src="java.js"></script> and the .js is in the same directory. I have a feeling im barking completly up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Again, I'll ask... Have you looked at the Developer's Tools Console on the page that isn't working?

Comment: Apologies Scott, Ibve not used that before but this is the error on that tab - TypeError: countdown is null[Learn More] Index.html:36:2
    getCountdown http://www.spautotech.co.uk/Index.html:36
    <anonymous> http://www.spautotech.co.uk/Index.html:16

Comment: That's not the error I see. I see: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script>` element that contains your countdown code is inserted into your HTML document before the `<body>` tag. In that code, you have:

```
var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element
```

But, at this point in the page processing, none of the content in the `body` has been parsed and so `countdown` is `null`. Later, when you try to set the `.innerHTML` of `countdown`:

```
countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>";
```

It fails because `countdown` was never found.

**SOLUTION:**

Pick up your entire `<script>` and move it so that it is just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`) because, by that time, all the HTML will have been parsed.

### Or...

If you continue to use JQuery, you can take the entire contents of your `<script>` and place it inside of JQuery's [`document.ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) method to establish your code as code that should only run once the document has been fully parsed:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     // All your code would go in here

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Fantastic - I did it the first way and was successfull
Thank you for the help

I think I need to go a little further to basics here and get a better understanding of what im doing.

Comment: @user3254111 But, you do still have two errors in your page because of bad references to external scripts.