# Why am I unable to load my css file after redirecting using express?

Tags: javascript, css, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

So I am using express and express-handlebars. Everything is working correctly in that when I go to a url that corresponds to a get method I have and it renders a page, evreything is fine it loads the page with the css file. I have a form with a submit button that when clicked will render a page with the css just fine. However, if I try to redirect first (upon clicking sumbit) and then render a page from the new redirected get method, it doesn't work. Instead I get an error: "The resource from [URL] was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).". Can anyone explain to me whats going on here.

Ok update. It works only if I specify this: app.use("/routes/:author", express.static("public")); . But do I really have to create a static folder for every redirect?

These are the three express use methods I'm using

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use("/routes", express.static("public"));
app.use("/routes/:author", express.static("public"));
```

First I go to my form.hbs

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => res.render("form"));
```

Then I click submit which has a href set to "/form" and I send a parameter

```
router.post("/form", (req, res) => res.redirect(`/routes/${model.author}`));
```

Which redirects me to "/:author" and renders my data.hbs

```
router.get("/:author", (req, res) => res.render("data"));
```

This works fine now.
If however, I remove, for example

```
app.use("/routes/:author", express.static("public"));
```

The css file for data.hbs does not load and I then get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: _"But do I really have to create an static folder for every redirect?"_ Of course not, that would be hell :) Please show us some code: the routes you've created, and the URLs you are using in your HTML to link to the CSS file. And possibily anything else that you think might help us figure out what's wrong. The `MIME type` error you get might indicate that the URL for the CSS file in not correct, and an HTML document is loaded instead. If you have subpaths in your URLs, you might want to use links relative to the root of your site: `/css/style.css` so it works no matter the page you're on

Comment: @Serious The HTML document loaded instead that blex refers to could be a 404 page, if that makes it clearer.

Comment: Blex's solution worked. Should I delete the question or leave it up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528748/function-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosniff). Although some parts of the question appear to be different, the solution is the same. I think that you can accept the duplicate flag, and so other people will be guided to the answer from this question.